How can I detect if two peaks are at the same horizontal level with a threshold that works across different intervals in an OHLCV dataset in Python?
I am working with an OHLCV (Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) dataset and need to detect whether two peaks are at the same horizontal level within a certain threshold. Currently, I am using an angular threshold. For example, I check if the angle between two peaks (P1-P2) is within ±10° to consider them at the same level.
This works fine for data at the daily interval (1-day), but it breaks down when I apply it to other intervals like 1-minute data. Even after scaling the data, the algorithm performs differently across different timeframes.
Is there a more robust algorithm or approach I could use to detect whether peaks are at the same level, independent of the time interval? My goal is to have a method that performs consistently for various timeframes, from 1-minute to 1-day data.

please, show your code, show sample data, matching and mismatching (copy/paste - no screenshots)
